# Editing gender syntax error

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a select drop down option to edit student gender for my website.

```
<tr>
                    <td>Gender:</td>
        <?php
                    echo '<td bgcolor="lightgray"><input type="text" readonly="true" value="'.$StudentObject->sGender.'"></td>';
                    <td><select name="sgender" id="sgender">
                            <option value='Male'> Male </option>
                            <option value='Female'> Female </option>
                            </select>
                    </td>
        ?>

                </tr>
```

But it says Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'. I don't know what seems to be the problem because I'm still beginner in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP Closing tag should be after your echo statement and not at the end.

```
<tr>
                <td>Gender:</td>
    <?php
                echo '<td bgcolor="lightgray"><input type="text" readonly="true" value="'.$StudentObject->sGender.'"></td>';
    ?>
                <td><select name="sgender" id="sgender">
                        <option value='Male'> Male </option>
                        <option value='Female'> Female </option>
                        </select>
                </td>


            </tr>
```